# Woocommerce: Add the category thumbnail image to my sidebar in product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, sidebar

I'm using WooCommerce widgets to add the category list for my products in the sidebar of my website. Currently the categories are listed as text items. I would like to display the thumbnail image for each category (beside the text).

I have used code below, but it shows the category thumbnail in the centre of the page where the products are listed:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
        }
}
```

I would like this thumbnails in the sidebar beside the text items.

What am I missing to achieve this?

Comment: Hi, did you find some better solution ? less coding. Thank you. Since I think this is very common use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have picked this code snippet at wooThemes: [WC Display category image on category archive](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/)

You are using [*woocommerce_archive_description*](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_archive_description/hook) that is displaying this category image on `archive-product.php` template (line 48).

Sorry but this will not work for a widget especially using this hook.

Now you have 3 options:

- Creating your own widget and coding it with php (the hardest).
- Using a free plugin made for that: [WooCommerce - Category widget](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-category-widget/) (the easiest)
- Or in between, picking some code and ideas in the plugin, to make your own…

Comment: The XO10 - WooCommerce Categories widget plugin works better for something to edit but your suggestions are accurate. Thank you.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help. I will work on it & create a new question with some new code. I was wondering if there was a quick solution for this question; I currently have the sidebar displaying the parent category the user is in, followed by all of the subcategories. Do you know a way in which I can remove that initial current parent category link?